# What is the best option to deploy Redis on docker for Production?

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose, flask-restful, amazon-elasticache

I am trying to deploy my flask application with on docker with Redis as a container. I have docker-compose and everything setup and running. I am not running docker swamp though.
I keep reading conflicting information on the internet about the best way to deploy Redis on production. Some are suggesting supervisor and others Elastic Cache.
I am more interested in how to manage Redis and restart workers automatically if I do not use docker swarm.
I am new to the deployment world and I am little confused as to the best way to deploy my application.

I am deploying my App on AWS EC2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ElasticCache is only relevant if you're hosting your application AWS, but ElastiCache gives you two options of using Memcache or Redis anyway, so not much is changed there. ElastiCache is basically just a wrapper around Redis or Memcache, much like ECS is a wrapper around Docker.

I don't see what the problem is with having your Redis running off of a container in production.

Comment: First, sorry I didn't make it clear where I am deploying my application. I am deploying it on AWS EC2. Secondly I there is no problem using containers in production.  I want to know the best option to deploying my application with Redis. I was just worried about how my workers would restart if I do not use docker swarm or kubs

Comment: Its difficult to answer your question without knowing your stack and architecture, but if you're using redis, its better to use redis through Elasticache as its native to AWS